# How to add 3 templates to custom tabs

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, javascript, css, tabs

I have 3 blocks that are in the cms block and displayed on the cms page.
How to place each block in a separate custom tab

Tabs stretched to full page
[image]

3 templates:

```
app/code/Qqq/Wwwww/view/frontend/templates/template1.phtml
app/code/Qqq/Wwwww/view/frontend/templates/template2.phtml
app/code/Qqq/Wwwww/view/frontend/templates/template3.phtml
```

cms block install script:

```
app/code/Qqq/Wwwww/Setup/InstallData.php
```

```
 $block = <<<BLOCK_CONTENT
   <div class="block-1">block 1</div>
   {{block class="Qqq\Wwwww\Block\Qw" name="block_1" template="Qqq_Wwww::template1.phtml"}}
   <div class="block-2">block 2</div>
   {{block class="Qqq\Wwwww\Block\Qw" name="block_2" template="Qq_Wwww::template2.phtml"}}
   <div class="block-3">block 3</div>
   {{block class="Qqq\Wwwww\Block\Qw" name="block_3" template="Qq_Wwww::template3.phtml"}}
BLOCK_CONTENT;

 $cmsBlock = [
     'title' => 'Block 1',
     'identifier' => 'blocks',
     'stores' => [0],
     'is_active' => 1,
     'content' => $block
 ];

 $this->blockFactory->create()->setData($cmsBlock)->save();
```

cms page install script:

```
$pageContent = <<<PAGE_CONTENT
    {{block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" block_id="blocks"}}
PAGE_CONTENT;

        $cmsPageData = [
            'title' => 'Blocks Page', // cms page title
            'page_layout' => '1column', // cms page layout
            'meta_keywords' => 'Blocks Page', // cms page meta keywords
            'meta_description' => 'Blocks Page', // cms page description
            'identifier' => 'blocks-page', // cms page url identifier
            'content_heading' => '', // Page heading
            'content' => $pageContent, // page content
            'is_active' => 1, // define active status
            'stores' => [0], // assign to stores
            'sort_order' => 0 // page sort order
        ];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
For HTML custom tab using below link:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_full_page_tabs
According to me you no need to create CMS block, direct create one CMS page with below code:
<button id="defaultOpen" class="tablink">Block1</button>
<button class="tablink">Block2</button> 
<button class="tablink">Block3</button>
<div id="Block1" class="tabcontent">
<h3>Block1</h3>
{{block class="Solwin\Module4\Block\Qw" name="block_1" template="Solwin_Module4::template1.phtml"}}</div>
<div id="Block2" class="tabcontent">
<h3>Block2</h3>
{{block class="Solwin\Module4\Block\Qw" name="block_1" template="Solwin_Module4::template2.phtml"}}</div>
<div id="Block3" class="tabcontent">
<h3>Block3</h3>
{{block class="Solwin\Module4\Block\Qw" name="block_1" template="Solwin_Module4::template3.phtml"}}</div>
Don't forget to add CSS style and Javascript code from above given link.
Image: custom_tab.png
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try this code

```
$block = <<<BLOCK_CONTENT

<div class="product data items"
     data-mage-init='{"mage/tabs": {"openedState": "active", "animate": {"duration": 100}, "active": 1, "disabled": [2], "disabledState": "disabled"}}'>
    <div class="item title" data-role="collapsible">
        <a class="switch" data-toggle="trigger" href="#tab-block-1">Block - 1</a>
    </div>
    <div id="tab-block-1" class="item content" data-role="content">
        {{block class="Qqq\Wwwww\Block\Qw" name="block_1" template="Qqq_Wwww::template1.phtml"}}
    </div>

    <div class="item title" data-role="collapsible">
        <a class="switch" data-toggle="trigger" href="#tab-block-2">Block - 2</a>
    </div>
    <div id="tab-block-2" class="item content" data-role="content">
        {{block class="Qqq\Wwwww\Block\Qw" name="block_2" template="Qq_Wwww::template2.phtml"}}
    </div>

    <div class="item title" data-role="collapsible">
        <a class="switch" data-toggle="trigger" href="#tab-block-3">Block - 3</a>
    </div>
    <div id="tab-block-3" class="item content" data-role="content">
        {{block class="Qqq\Wwwww\Block\Qw" name="block_3" template="Qq_Wwww::template3.phtml"}}
    </div>
</div>

BLOCK_CONTENT;

 $cmsBlock = [
     'title' => 'Block 1',
     'identifier' => 'blocks',
     'stores' => [0],
     'is_active' => 1,
     'content' => $block
 ];

 $this->blockFactory->create()->setData($cmsBlock)->save();
```